# EAV collection problem with Customer entity

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, eav, customer-attribute

(Magento CE V1.7.0.2)

I have a problem with the customer data collection, I can't have any "telephone" number.

I must remove the line

```
->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

from `_prepareCollection()` function of Grid.php for the customer table list or I have an error report with:

```
"Attribute type not valid" /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(652): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Type d'attribut...')
```

How can I rebuild default EAV attribute or perhaps someone has modified a file?

Comment: To check if the attribute is really missing (this is what the error message suggests), have a look at your database and check if the table `eav_attribute` contains an entry with `attribute_code='telephone'` and `entity_type_id=2`.

Comment: Here is the line : http://www.evoweb.fr/divers/eav_attribute_telephone.jpg and the "entity_type_id" is at 1
Should I modify it ?

Comment: Yes, this is the row that would have type 2 by default ("1" is for customers, "2" is for customer addresses). If you need a telephone attribute for the customer as well, copy the row (by default this does not exist).

Comment: All is working good now. Thank you a lot for your help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information from the comments: The `telephone` attribute should look like this:

```
mysql> select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='telephone';
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code | attribute_model | backend_model | backend_type | backend_table | frontend_model | frontend_input | frontend_label | frontend_class | source_model | is_required | is_user_defined | default_value | is_unique | note |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
|           31 |              2 | telephone      | NULL            | NULL          | varchar      | NULL          | NULL           | text           | Telephone      | NULL           | NULL         |           0 |               0 | NULL          |         0 | NULL |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
```

In your case somebody/something has changed the entity type id from `2` to `1`, to associate the phone number to the customer instead of the customer address.

But Magento expects the address attribute to exist, so you need to restore the original attribute. If you need the customer to have a telephone number as well, you can duplicate the row and keep it with `entity_type_id` 1 and 2, both. It is possible to have the same attribute code for different entity types.